# What happened to the cat Jones from Alien and Aliens?

Tags: alien-franchise, alien-1979, aliens-1986

In *Alien* and *Aliens*, Ripley had a cat named Jones. In *Aliens* when Ripley is preparing to go to LV426 with the marines she says to Jones,

> "And you, you little shit-head, you're staying here."

So presumably the cat was left behind.

What ever happened to Jones? Was there additional fiction or interviews that covered this?

Comment: That cat later married an alien, which estranged it from Ripley.

Comment: I know this is a popular topic.  It seems people are just Jonesing for an answer about that cat.

Comment: He avoided the rest of the flopping Alien Franchise and lived happily ever after making Meow Mix commercials.

Comment: @Tango - It would be nice if we could get a cat-egorical answer, or at the very least proof paw-sitive that he's alive.

Comment: @Valorum: Or alive and feline fine...

Comment: @Tango - That joke was a-paw-ling.

Comment: @Valorum: Sorry you thought it was a cat-astrophe.

Comment: He's the only cat to have ever faced a xenomorph and live to tell about it. Obviously, his future back on earth involved lots and lots of... kittens.

Comment: Cat? That’s a [Flerken](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/207012/are-all-cats-flerkens).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**He died,** at least according to the [Alien<sup>3</sup> novelisation](http://avp.wikia.com/wiki/Alien_3_(novel)) by Alan Dean Foster. The implication is that he remained on Gateway or was rehomed on Earth where he lived out the remainder of his life.

> She found herself thinking of Jonesy. No one wonder she and the cat
>   had survived the Nostromo. Curiosity and a talent for survival were
>   two of the skills they’d shared.
>
> **Jonesy was gone now, a victim of the time distortions made necessary
>   by space travel.** No more cat-nightmares for him. Only she was left to
>   deal with life, and all the memories.

---

Note that Ripley is *assuming* that he's dead, rather than having positive knowledge. There's the (vanishingly slim) possibility that he's being kept in hyper-suspension for some reason and could [return in a future outing](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BackFromTheDead).

Comment: This deserved more [+]'s just for the suggestion Jonesy could return :)

Comment: @Pelinore - Given the dearth of creativity in Hollywood, I'm sure a Jonesy spinoff is already in the works.

Answer (score 31):

From the Alien and Predator wiki, it is unclear what happened (and people have tried to find out, because this is one of the most-asked questions about Alien and Aliens):

> Ripley and Jones remained in cryostasis for 57 years. The salvage crew that picked them up initially thought the unusual readings from the cryotube was that of an alien life form, but visual inspection revealed to them that they were simply reading the human and feline sets of DNA as one organism. After their recovery, they were reunited in the hospital of Gateway Station by Carter Burke. Jones then went to stay with Ripley at her new apartment. **It is unclear what became of Jones after Ripley's assignment to the USS Sulaco.**

Here is the link to the wikipage about the cat: http://avp.wikia.com/wiki/Jones_%28cat%29

Answer (score 0):

Just started the game, *Aliens: Infestation*, on the Nintendo DS which takes place on LV-426 some time after *Aliens*. Early on, a cat looking like Jones jumps out at the Marines as the first jump-scare of the game so it seems Jones is/was still was alive by that point. Will update if anything changes. =)

Comment: Jones never went to LV-426. He stayed on Earth/in Earth orbit.

Comment: @gnovice Was Gateway over Earth?

Comment: @Xantec: [Yep.](http://avp.wikia.com/wiki/Gateway_Station)

Comment: @gnovice: well, we never *saw* him/her go to LV-426, but it could have happened later.

Answer (score -2):

Jonesy is dead. In Aliens the team was in hyper to get to the planet. If the hospital where Ripley woke was near Earth, the amount of light years to LV426 is about 39. Jonesy lived out his years like a normal cat most likely.

Comment: You are mistaken. The travel time in the Sulaco (a state-of-the-art military transport) from Gateway to LV-426 was only a few weeks. He was almost certainly alive *throughout the entire events of Aliens.* He would have died subsequently.

Answer (score -3):

Cat "Jonesy" remained in the Gateway station, the only one who had close encounter with Alien and survived :)

Comment: Where is your source for this information?